# How to install duplicati 2.0 on debian?

Tags: debian, duplicati

I have a problem when I install debian distro on Duplicati. I'm trying :
`sudo apt-get install mono-complete
cd /usr/lib
mkdir Duplicati
cd Duplicati
wget http://updates.duplicati.com/preview/latest.zip
unzip latest.zip
mono Duplicati.GUI.TrayIcon.exe`

I have the following error message:

'Missing method System.Threading.Tasks.Task :: WhenAll (Task []) in /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll assembly, referenced in assembly /usr/lib/duplicati/Duplicati.Library.UsageReporter.dll
Crash!'
and more...

do you have an idea about the problem?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have tested on Ubuntu, and I have not seen that issue before.

What version of Mono do you have installed?
Try: `mono --version`

The error is that the System.Threading.Task library is missing a required method, which indicates that you are using some strange version of the Mono libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Good ! many thanks Kenneth ! i tested with :
'echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-libtiff-compat main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list'
from mono-project.com and it works !!